# Regex on <STDIN> not finding matches - Perl

Tags: regex, windows, perl, utf-8, stdin

I'm trying to make a script that would take in a string with accented characters, and return their unaccented counterparts.

I managed to make something that almost works after looking around for some help and tutorials, but I have a problem.

My code does what I want, as long as I want it done on a simple string, but it does absolutely nothing when I want to use `<STDIN>`.

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my %replace = (
    'é' => "e",
    'á' => "a",
    'ő' => "o",
    'ö' => "o",
    'ó' => "o",
    'ú' => "u",
    'ü' => "u",
    'ű' => "u",
    'í' => "i",    
);

my $regex = join "|", keys %replace;
$regex = qr/$regex/;

my $s = <STDIN>;
$s = substr $s, 0, length($s) - 1;

my $var = "$s - öüóőúéáű";

$var =~ s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;

$s = $var;

print "$s\n";
```

If i input "öüóőúéáű" to `<STDIN>` i get the following output:

`öüóőúéáű - ouooueau`

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I checked, and when using it like the following (with `<DATA>` instead of `<STDIN>`) it works properly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %replace = (
    'é' => "e",
    'á' => "a",
    'ő' => "o",
    'ö' => "o",
    'ó' => "o",
    'ú' => "u",
    'ü' => "u",
    'ű' => "u",
    'í' => "i",    
);

my $regex = join "|", keys %replace;
$regex = qr/$regex/;

my $s = <DATA>;
$s = substr $s, 0, length($s) - 1;

my $var = "$s - öüóőúéáű";

$var =~ s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;

$s = $var;

print "$s\n";

__DATA__
öüóőúéáű
```

EDIT2:

I now did the following: `my $s = <DATA>." - ".<>;` so it reads in the characters from `<DATA>` as well as from `<STDIN>` and now I realized, that it still matches with `<DATA>` and does noting to `<STDIN>`, so i get the following output:

`uaeuoouoi - űáéúőóüöí - uaeuoouoi` from the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my %replace = (
    'é' => "e",
    'á' => "a",
    'ő' => "o",
    'ö' => "o",
    'ó' => "o",
    'ú' => "u",
    'ü' => "u",
    'ű' => "u",
    'í' => "i",    
);

my $regex = join "|", keys %replace;
$regex = qr/$regex/;



my $s = <DATA>." - ".<>;
$s = substr $s, 0, length($s) - 1;

my $var = "$s - űáéúőóüöí";

$var =~ s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;

$s = $var;

print "$s\n";

__DATA__
űáéúőóüöí
```

where `<STDIN>` = űáéúőóüöí

Comment: `use open qw(:std :utf8);`

Comment: @Сухой27 I added that to the top of my script, now when adding an accented character i get the following: `utf8 "\xA0" does not map to Unicode at regex.pl line 20, <STDIN> line 1. Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected end of string) in length at regex.pl line 22, <STDIN> line 1.`

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: @Сухой27 Yes, Windows 8 Pro x64

Answer (score 2):

In my case with your program I get the expected result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my %replace = (
    'é' => "e",
    'á' => "a",
    'ő' => "o",
    'ö' => "o",
    'ó' => "o",
    'ú' => "u",
    'ü' => "u",
    'ű' => "u",
    'í' => "i",    
);

my $regex = join "|", keys %replace;
$regex = qr/$regex/;

my $s = <DATA>;
$s = substr $s, 0, length($s) - 1;

my $var = "$s - öüóőúéáű";

$var =~ s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;

$s = $var;

print "$s\n";

__DATA__
öüóőúéáű
```

Where I get:

```
$ perl test.pl
ouooueau - ouooueau
```

So you have another problem such as an encoding issue.

You can try to add to your program.

```
use utf8;
```

Also you can simplify your program like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %replace = (
    'é' => "e",
    'á' => "a",
    'ő' => "o",
    'ö' => "o",
    'ó' => "o",
    'ú' => "u",
    'ü' => "u",
    'ű' => "u",
    'í' => "i",    
);

while(<DATA>) {
    for my $key (keys %replace) {
        s/$key/$replace{$key}/;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
öüóőúéáű
```

Comment: Hmm... well I guess it could be an issue with the PC (I'm on a company PC) Thanks though!

Comment: Actually, i checked your reply, and tried it using `<DATA>` and that way it works for me as well, so i guess there has to be something different about `<STDIN>`

Comment: @WolfyD Can you provide the values of `echo $TERM` and `echo $LANG` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these, where should i find these values? Perl or somewhere else?

Comment: --Also if they may be Linux variables, I'm on Windows, so I won't be able to tell you.

Comment: Well, this means your terminal is not UTF-8. Windows console has different encoding and if your Perl Script is written in utf-8 it won't work. Try `chcp` on `cmd.exe`. Also maybe this can help you: [question](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes, `chcp` returns 852, so i guess I'll have to work around that